# Adding total at the end of each row in the table in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

How to add total for selected columns in the table in SSRS.Please see the attached image file below.I have tried "add total" from the group. But it displays at the end of group footer.I wanted the total for columns  and displayed at the end of each row. Could anyone please help me to do that? TIA
[image: Total column at the end of each row]

Answer (score 1):

Add a column at the end of the row that has an expression that adds all the other columns together.

I don't know your column names, but assuming they were the same as your headers it would look something like:

```
=ReportItems!Current + ReportItems!30-59 + ReportItems!60-89 + ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I added a column expression as =Fields!ID30__59.Value+Fields!ID60___89.Value+Fields!ID90_119.Value+... but it is not giving the correct sum answer. Could you please let me know what is the wrong in query. Are the field and  report items different?

Comment: The fields collection gets the value from the dataset.   The ReportItems gets the value of the cell in the tablix.   They could be the same or different depending on what expressions you are using in the report.

Comment: Where can I find ReportItems collection?

Comment: The ReportItems are the names of your report elements.   So if you have the value of ID30__59 in a textbox named `Textbox59`, you would reference it in the ReportItems collection like:   `ReportItems!Textbox59.Value`.    Of course, to see the name of a specific report item, just select it and look for the `Name` property in the properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I have added sum of dataset fields instead of single value for the field.It might be because of grouping. In the expression editor I put Sum(Fields!ID30__59.Value)+sum(Fields!ID60__89.Value)+.. , it gives total value for the required columns in each row.